# S3 Intelligent-Tiering objects aren't moved to archive class

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

A week ago I have enabled Intelligent-Tiering configuration in a bucket:

```
180 Days until transition to Archive Access tier
360 Days until transition to Deep Archive Access tier
```

Then I moved objects to Intelligent-Tiering class via lifecycle policy.

Why my example object still has no archive class despite the fact that it's last_modified date is more than a year ago? I'm sure that it hasn't been accessed (downloaded) also.

Comment: Since you just moved that object into Intelligent-tiering class, AWS monitors that object class from that day under intelligent-tiering, not the last modified date I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter if your object last modified date was a year ago. The policy is only affected after you have applied it since *START* day. AWS monitors that object starting from your *START* day and apply the tier automatically based on your configuration.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intelligent-tiering-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

You seem missing the concept of Intelligent-Tiering that the object which is **not accessed for XX days are moved**.

In the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intelligent-tiering-overview.html):

**Archive Access tier**

> S3 Intelligent-Tiering provides you
> with the option to enable the Archive Access tier to automatically
> archive objects that have *not been accessed* for a minimum of 90
> consecutive days.

**Deep Archive Access tier**

> S3 Intelligent-Tiering provides you with the option to enable the Deep
> Archive Access tier to automatically archive objects that have *not
> been accessed* for a minimum of 180 consecutive days.

Comment: Is object properties lookup through S3 GUI considered as object accessing?

Comment: I searched but couldn't find the exact description for access time definition in AWS. But normally access time is updated for read/write actions. So lookup through S3 GUI is not be considered as access.